# How can image view through the hollow text in tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css

How to hide the bg-cover image and display the image part only through the overlay text ( ie see through text or hollow text) part alone using tailwind css.
Could someone please advise ?

```
 <div class="relative w-full md:w-3/5">
    <div class="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden">
      <img src="images/hometopImg.png" alt="Image" class="w-full h-full object-cover"/>
      <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-50">
        <h1 class="text-white text-4xl font-bold">FILL</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use your image "images/hometopImg.png" as `background-image` for your h1 element.

Comment: @TimmyChan So are you advising to move the `<img src="images/hometopImg.png" alt="Image" class="w-full h-full object-cover"/>` inside the h1 tag ?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use your image as css background-image, instead of using the `img` tag. And then, `bg-clip-text` will clip the background-image using the text. `text-transparent` will make sure the color of the text is not covering the background-image.

Here is the code you need:

```
<h1 class="bg-[url('<your image url>')] bg-clip-text text-transparent">FILL</h1>
```

Make sure you **remove** your `img` element.

Comment: Great help, that worked accepted and upvoted